# Is it possible to update connection string of existing azure search indexers

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I am in the process of moving to a new database server and I have azure search indexers which are still pointing to my old database server, is it possible to update the connection strings of my azure search indexers without having to rebuild the indexes from the ground up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to update the connection strings of my azure search
> indexers without having to rebuild the indexes from the ground up?

Yes. It is entirely possible to do so.

However you would change the connection string in the data source settings and not in indexer settings.

You would simply need to update the data source with new connection string pointing to your new database and your indexer should pick up the data from the new database on its next run. In other words, simply change the connection string of the data source to point to the new database.

You can do so in Azure Portal. Simply find the data source and change its connection string to point to the new database.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please refer me some documentation where I can find more details

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean by `update data source with connection string`, still looking for help

Comment: When you create a data source, you specify a connection string to the database. When I say `update data source with connection string`, what I mean is that you update your data source by changing the connection string so that now your data source points to the new database instead of old database. You can change it in Azure Portal. I have updated my answer and included some screenshots from there. HTH.